# Set home directory for current session?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run some programs which depend on a home directory, but my current user does not have a home directory defined. I don't want to create a user just to run this program, and I don't want to run it as root. Is there a way to define a home directory (eg /tmp) for just the current session? So that, for example, `~` is defined in bash.

Comment: `~` is shorthand for `$HOME` as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by issuing `export HOME=/tmp` in your user session.

There's plenty of explanation on the *tilde expansion* in the bash man page.